# How to present negative number in bitvector?

Tags: z3, theorem-proving, satisfiability

The title says it all. I try to present -1 as the following: `(_ bv-1 32)`, and z3 complains.

How do I present constraint such as `3x - 5y <= 10` in bit vector? For some reason, I do not want to use linear integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done via [two's complement encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The short version is,

```
-x = flip(x) + 1
```

where `flip(x)` simply flips all the bits in `x`.

Comment: Thank you. What is the syntax to flip all the bits in SMTLIB2 format?

Comment: That should be (bvnot x).